# No graphical interface at start-up

Tags: 14.04, graphics, startup

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 32bits.  Suddendly at startup appears a black screen asking for my username and password, with a low graphics interface.  After entering this nothing happens, only the cursor moves (a big cross cursor). Also it is not possible to open the console with Crt-alt-T.

Using the advanced options of Grub2 (open in recovery mode or low graphics mode) does not work either.

Comment: Are you able to use the Ctrl+Alt+F1/F2 command to get a full terminal? If yes you can try to backup your files, and maybe reinstall the desktop.

Comment: Yes, I could use Ctrl+Alt+F1 and had access to the full terminal.  I remove the nvidia files and reinstall nvidia. With the following instructions: sudo apt-get purge nvidia* bumblebee* and sudo apt-get install nvidia-prime

Comment: So it's solved now?

Answer (score 0):

Solved by OP in comments

> I remove[d] the NVIDIA files and reinstall NVIDIA, with the following
>   instructions
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get purge nvidia* bumblebee*
> ```
>
> then
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install nvidia-prime
> ```